# How to use Gmail API from Lotus Domino to migrate mail?

Tags: gmail-api

We are migrating our mail from our local Lotus Domino server to Google Apps for Work.
There is a desire to move users mail from their domino mailboxes to google domain accounts.
Offered solution to use GAMIN to migrate mail is not appropriate because our server runs on Linux.

What are possibilities to access Gmail API from Lotus agents?
Or maybe better solution is to build external utility with access to both gmail api and lotus api?

Answer (score 0):

You've seen there's a Google Apps Migration for IBM (Lotus) Notes tool, provided by Google, right?  Search for that and there's links to docs and the tool.

Comment: That tool uses service_account_com.dll which i cannnot utilize.
The manual about GAMIN that i've found is only about usage, not internals.